# Grub boots to a command line

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Recently I installed Ubuntu 18.04.02 on my Acer Aspire e15 laptop. I have it set up with Ubuntu on a hard drive (300GB) and Windows 10 on an SSD (256GB), and I'd like to be able to dual boot them. I booted into a live session of Ubuntu from a USB thumb drive and choose the "Install alongside windows" option. The installation was successful, so I rebooted, and up came a grub command line, which gave me the:

```
Minimal BASH-like ending is supported. For the first word,TAB lists possible commands
completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions. ESC at anytime 
exits.
```

After a bunch of searching, I found I can boot into grub as it should be by running these commands:

```
set prefix=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,msdos6)
insmod linux
insmod normal
normal
```

After hitting enter on the last `normal`, it boots into the grub environment where I can boot into either Windows or Ubuntu. Once I shut down and boot back up, however, it brings me back to the command line. So I've spent quite a while looking through forms and trying all the options.

Here are a few things I've tried that have led to no avail: 
In Ubuntu, I've run the `sudo update-grub` in the terminal, which ran just fine, but didn't change where grub boots to.

I then tried the Boot Repair program, which did nothing except add a bunch of entries into grub, so now instead of listing just Ubuntu and Windows, there are a bunch of paths to .efi files.

Next I tried `sudo grub-install`, which gave me errors saying "Couldn't find disk /dev/sda. Attempting /dev/sda5", which then did nothing.

I have done absolutely nothing with Linux before and I'm a beginner in most of the computer world.

Just before posting this question, my dad said I had to put this on here: I'm only 15 years old, and have done absolutely nothing with Linux before and I'm a beginner in most of the computer world. If you wouldn't mind dumbing down your answer a little so I could understand, that would be great! :) Thank you for helping me out!

Here is the results of `sudo parted - l`
[image: Here is the results of <code>sudo parted -l</code>]

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Note that Acer typically needs UEFI update to latest from Acer and if SSD, latest firmware for SSD and then "trust" setting in UEFI. Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: This can happen if you accidentally deleted a boot entry or updated grub incorrectly. (Or, if you touch the C key...)